# Count frequencies of string - using only stdio.h - C

Tags: c, char, substring, c-strings, cyclic

We have got some exercise in C (We must use only stdio.h library):

> Write a function that receives two strings and returns the number of occurences of the second in the first one, there could be overlapping dependent on cyclic parameter.

**But I don't succeed treat the case of isCyclic is turned on.**

for example if isCyclic is other than 0 and:

> char *str1 = "aaa";
>   char *str2 = "aa";
>   We have to return 3

What is my mistake in isCyclic?..

Here is my implementation:

```
int strLength(const char *str) {
    int count = 0;

    while (*str) {
        count++;
        str++;
    }

    return count;
}

unsigned int countPatInStr(const char *str1, const char *str2, int isCyclic)
{
    int patternSize = strLength(str2);
    int textSize = strLength(str1);
    int res = 0;
    int j;

    if (isCyclic) { // Here is the case when overlapping is needed
        if (patternSize > textSize) {
            for (int i = 0; i < patternSize - textSize; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < textSize; j++) {
                    if (str1[j] != str2[i + j]) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (j == textSize && i + j < patternSize) {
                        str2 += i + j;
                    } else if (j == textSize && i + j == patternSize) {
                        res++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        /* A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
        for (int i = 0; i <= textSize - patternSize; i++) {
            /* For current index i, check for pattern match */
            for (j = 0; j < patternSize; j++) {
                if (str1[i + j] != str2[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1]
            if (j == patternSize) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it true that str2 length will always be <= str1 length. Or str2 length can be greater than str1 length. ex: countPatInStr("aa","aaa",1) what will be output in this case.

Comment: when isCycled is on, add `str1` to itself except the last char (`abc` ==> `abcab` or `aa` ==> `aaa`) and then use the method for when isCycled is off

Comment: Could you edit your question with an example of current wrong behaviour, with input and output? Also your question would improve if you made it a minimal working example, by adding the main and the includes so it can be compiled.

Also, have a look a this meta question about homeworks:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @HimanshuSingh The str2 length can be greater than str1 length. I know that for example if str1 is "ab" and str2 is aba then the result is 1 while isCyclic is on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function at least is invalid because in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < patternSize - textSize; i++)
```

the condition can be equal to false. So the loop is never executed.

And in this loop

```
            for (int j = 0; j < textSize; j++) {
                if (str1[j] != str2[i + j]) {
                    break;
                }
```

there is used the index `j` with the pointer `str1` and the index `i + j` with the pointer `str2` when `isCyclic` is non-zero.

The function can be written much simpler as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t strLength( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s ) ++n;

    return n;
}

size_t countPatInStr( const char *s1, const char *s2, _Bool isCyclic )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    size_t n1 = strLength( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strLength( s2 );


    if ( !( n1 < n2 ) || isCyclic )
    {
        size_t n = isCyclic ? n1 : n1 - n2 + 1;
        size_t divident = isCyclic ? n : n1;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            while ( j < n2 && s1[ ( i + j ) % divident] == s2[j] ) j++;

            count += j == n2;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "aaa";
    const char *s2 = "aa";

    printf( "%zu\n", countPatInStr( s1, s2, 0 ) );
    printf( "%zu\n", countPatInStr( s1, s2, 1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
3
```

Or if `s1` and `s2` are defined like

```
const char *s1 = "aa";
const char *s2 = "aaa";
```

then the output will be

```
0
2
```

Or if they are defined like

```
const char *s1 = "abcabc";
const char *s2 = "abc";
```

then the output is

```
2
2
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: The strings can be like: *str1 = "abcabc"; *str2 = "abc"; In this case the result is 2 and this solution gives 1. They also may be: *str1 = "abc"; *str2 = "abca"; Where this solution gives 0 and expected 1. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, amazing. But, I'm trying now figuring this solution out and there are some obstacles. We didn't learn the notation of '?'. Do you have an alternative for that? And can you explain a little bit the logic of this while?             while ( j < n2 && s1[ ( i + j ) % divident] == s2[j] ) j++; Thank you!!

Comment: @HelpMe You can substitute the conditional operator for an if-else statement. For example size_t n; if (  isCyclic  ) n = n1; else n = n1 - n2 + 1;

Comment: Can you explain briefly the logic here? In particular of the while. Thank you.

Comment: @HelpMe The while loop compares a substring of s1 with the string s2. If after the loop j is equal to n2 then all symbols were equal to each other.

Comment: What is the value of divident for?

Comment: @HelpMe To get initial indices when i + j is greater than n1.

Comment: What n1 - n2 + 1 represents?

Comment: @HelpMe The upper limits of the loop iterators when isCycllc is set to 0. For example if the two strings have the same size then at least one iteration of the outer loop shall be done.

Comment: Actually I have runned valgrind and it says we have floating point exception. What's the matter?

Comment: @HelpMe There is no float numbers in the presented code.

Comment: The issue is with divident variable. It may be not initialized and it causes floating exception error when running valgrind (it is equivalent to divide by zero when not initialized).

Comment: @HelpMe The variable is initialized size_t divident = isCyclic ? n : n1; It seems you made your own changes that result in an error.

Comment: Yes. I first declared divident and n as size_t variables. Then I did assignments to them according to the if-conditions. In case the first if-condition is not true - then we don't assign to divident anything. I deliberately have changed this section of code as I can't use some operator like ? because we didn't learn that.

Comment: @HelpMe It can be defined like size_t divident; if ( isCyckic) { divident = n; } else { divident = n1;}